# Подключение к MSSQL Server через PDO ODBC

Tags: apache, pdo, php, odbc

Здравствуйте.
Пробую подключаться к MSSQL Server через PDO ODBC.
Тестовый файл test.php:

```
  <?php
  $query = 'select * from sysdatabases;';
  try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:SOURCENAME", "sa", "12895764");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("$query");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
?>
```

Если выполнить код через консоль, то подключение проходит и я получаю данные. Если этот файл выполнить через Apache, то выходит ошибка:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Драйвер и источник установил через odbcinst.
В чем может быть проблема?

tds.driver

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = v0.63 with protocol v8.0
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

tds.datasource

```
[SOURCENAME]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=Test MS SQL Database with FreeTDS
Trace=Yes
Server=192.168.1.8\SQLEXPRESS
TDS Version=8.0
Database=database
```

Вывод phpinfo [из консоли](http://pastebin.com/5gAgLubi) и из [web](http://pastebin.com/hg7sQMhZ)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. Файлы tds.driver и tds.datasource не нужны. Для того чтобы можно было подключиться надо в файл /etc/freetds/freetds.conf добавить:

```
[SOURCENAME]
  host=192.168.1.8\SQLEXPRESS
```

Это на Ubuntu 12.04. На других ОС файл конфигурации FreeTDS может находится в других местах.

[Еще одно решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452747/problems-with-unixodbc-and-freetds-config)

Answer (score 1):

Конфиг freetds..

```
[temp_sql]
        host = 192.168.1.28
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

И на его основе пишем подключение...

```
# Переменные для подключения к БД
$mssqlhost = 'temp_sql';    # Хост
$mssqlbase = 'temp_DB'; # БД
$mssqllogn = 'sqlguest';    # Логин 
$mssqlpass = 'sqlguest';    # Пароль

try {
    # Подключение к MSSQL  
    $DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$mssqlhost;dbname=$mssqlbase", "$mssqllogn", "$mssqlpass");
} catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    exit;
}
```

Увидеть список доступных драйверов можно так:

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```